# mean.default argument not numerical on R

Tags: r, numeric, mean

I'm trying to use R for the first time, I have never taken courses and have some questions. the first is this:
when I try to do the mean of some Temperature values (they are all between 18.15 and 18.40)
I get this answer 
"Warning message:
In mean.default(d_Temp_Experiment$value) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"
I dont' have the same problem with values of PAR 5that are all integer numbers and with values of pH all decimal numbers like 8.831...
Can you tell what I do wrong?

Comment: what does `class(d_Temp_Experiment$value)` give you?

Comment: How did you load the `$value` values?  It's possible they're `factors` or alternatively that the source text had a "bad" character that caused one or more elements to be treated as character rather than numeric.

Comment: I took the values from a file where there are values from a CTD, I've tried to find a "bad" character but i didn't see anything, they are all 18.15, 18.34 etc..

Comment: Could you enter `dput(head(d_TempExperiment))` and paste into your question the output? That will let us know exactly what your data looks like.

Comment: the out put when I enter dput (head(d_Temp_Experiment))  is:

structure(list(timedate = structure(c(1384440660, 1384440780, 
1384440900, 1384440960, 1384441140, 1384441260), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Temperature.Experiment.Box", class = "factor"), 
    value = c("18.37", "18.37", "18.37", "18.37", "18.37", "18.37"
    )), .Names = c("timedate", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arun hints at it could be that the column is character rather than numeric.
If you are sure that all the values are correct you could coerce the values with

```
d_Temp_Experiment$value <- as.numeric(d_Temp_Experiment$value)
```

You might have the below sort of business going on.

```
myvector <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,"6","7")
mv <- as.numeric(myvector)
mean(myvector)
mean(mv)
```

Comment: the answer is:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Value", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 614